# Finding an old patch in one of many git topic branches

Tags: git, git-branch

Like any good FLOSS developer I'm building up a number of local branches with various selections of patches in them. The trouble is when working on a topic I may have made a number of trivial patches which I was planning to extract later and submit upstream. Now I know the file that I patched but I can't remember what branch I was in at the time.

Is there an easy way to to query git "which branches have patches to path/to/file over and above what is in origin/master"?

Obviously I'm trying to avoid manually running "git log ${BRANCH} -- path/to/file" on every one of my topic branches by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method for finding the interesting *commits*:

```
git log --branches ^origin/master -- $file
```

(and I would generally add `--oneline` here).  The problem is that this gets commit IDs but does not tell you which branch(es) incorporate those commits.

Add `--decorate` and if any commits happen to be branch-tips, or are tagged, you'll get the names shown.  But let's say $file is modified in commit `d0gf00d`, for instance, and the chain goes like this (i.e., what you get from `git log --oneline --decorate --branches starts out with this):

```
badcafe (HEAD, master) make it all work
d0gf00d modify $file
affab1e (work) clean up documentation
2fab1e5 initial changes to $file
f1eeced (origin/master) preliminary version
...
```

Here, `d0gf00d` is on your branch `master` and not on `origin/master`.  Meanwhile commit `2fab1e5` is also on your branch `master` *and* on your branch `work`, and not on `origin/master`.  Other commits are on/below `origin/master`.  But, once you filter away commits `badcafe` and `affab1e`, the branch labels are no longer shown.

You can use `git branch --contains` to see (one at a time) which branch(es) have `d0gf00d` and `affab1e` in their history, but now you're back to looping in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seemed fairly easy to write a bash function for this. I'd still like to know if it's doable directly though.

```
#
# Report git log for a given file across all branches in the system
#
function git_branches_touching
{
    local file=$1
    local branches=()
    eval "$(git for-each-ref --shell --format='branches+=(%(refname))' refs/heads/)"
    for branch in "${branches[@]}"; do
        echo "Checking $branch"
        git log origin/master..$branch -- $file
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference I made a prettier utility script (which I call git branches-touching):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# List branches touching
#

hashes="`git log --format=format:"%H" --branches ^origin/master -- ${1}`"
for h in ${hashes}; do
    branches=`git branch --contains $h`
    git log --oneline --format=format:"%C(auto)%h (%Cgreen${branches##  }%Creset, %cr) %s" $h^..$h
done
```

Which when run gives this:

```
12:43 alex@zen/x86_64 [qemu.git/armv8-gdb-kvm@origin] >git branches-touching scripts/qemu-binfmt-conf.sh
04d15fc (armv8-migration, 3 months ago) scripts/qemu-binfmt-conf.sh: re-factor and clean-up
30bc3b4 (ajb-a64-system, 5 months ago) scripts/qemu-binfmt-conf.sh: re-factor and clean-up
406fb35 (ajb-a64-working, 7 months ago) scripts/qemu-binfmt-conf.sh: re-factor and clean-up
```